# No pointer events on Modal

Tags: react-native, pointer-events

Is there a way to set `pointerEvents` to `none` on a `Modal`? I'm trying to render a child view outside its parents bounds and the only way I could do this is by using a `Modal`. Ignoring `pointerEvents` on the child doesn't seem to work.

```
<View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
  <Modal
    animationType='fade'
    transparent={true}
    visible={true}
    pointerEvents='none'>
    <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} pointerEvents='none'>
    </View>
  </Modal>
</View>
```

Comment: Could you solve it? ... I have tried with heights, margins ... but nothing.

Comment: Hi there, were you able to figure this out? I also need to do same.

Comment: Which modal you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you mean this, because your description is not clear enough for me... but I also needed an Modal some time ago, which shouldn't be closed if I tap anywhere in the app, but only if I do a given Action (for me it was a Buttonclick in a Modal, after a given click-route).

And here is the way I solved it: I use `react-native-modalbox`, which does a really good Job for it.

With a plenty of possible options, you also can handle the click-behavior for the Modal.

**An small Example:**

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
 ... 
 ...
        <Modal
          style={[styles.audioToolbarModal, styles.audioToolbarBottomModal]}
          position="bottom"
          backdrop
          swipeToClose={false}
          coverScreen
          onOpened={() => this.startRecording()}
          isDisabled={modalIsDisabled}
          ref={(ref) => { this.audioToolbar = ref; }}
        >
```

The properties you might need are "isDisabled" (set this via State to toggle it), and `swipeToClose={false}`

I hope, this help you out.